# Вызов телефонного звонка из приложения (обработка исключений)

Tags: java, android

Для вызова телефонного звонка из приложения использую код:

```
androidVersion = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.RELEASE.substring(0, 1));
String contact_number="123456789";
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contact_number));
if (androidVersion < 5) callIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
        else callIntent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom");
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Т.е. если версия Андроид < 5, использую setPackage: "com.android.phone".
Версия 5 и более - использую setPackage: "com.android.server.telecom"

Но, как показала практика, не все смартфоны с 5 версией используют "com.android.server.telecom". 
Подскажите, плиз. как обработать такое исключение, чтобы не попасть на ".ActivityNotFoundException android.intent.action.CALL" и какой setPackage использовать в ОС Андроид 6.0 ?!

Заранее, благодарю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если попробовать вот так:

```
String contact_number="123456789";
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contact_number));
try {
    callIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
    startActivity(callIntent);
} catch(Exception e) {
    callIntent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom");
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Comment: В этом случае можно не проверять версию ОС Андроид?

Comment: Да. Вроде бы как не надо)

Comment: А в ОС Андроид 6.0 используется setPackage один из вышеперечисленных или в природе существует и третий?

Comment: Думается мне что в нем используется com.android.server.telecom, как и в пятой версии